# Why is this logging as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, lodash

I'm using jQuery and Lodash, and can't figure out why this is returning undefined:

```
$.each(someArray, function(i) {
  var x = _.find(someObject, function(item) {
    return item.Id === someArray[i]
  });
  console.log('x')
  console.log(x)
});
```

Comment: What is `someObject`, and what is `someArray`? Given `let someArray = [2], someObject = [{Id: 2, Label: 'String'}];`, I don't get undefined.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Returns the matched element, else undefined.

Meaning you don't have a match.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find

Now you need to figure out why.